# What is the simplest way of embedding another web page in my PHP script

Tags: php, embedding

I have a simple PHP script that needs to parse the content of another webpage. What is the easiest way to put the HTML code into a PHP variable?

Comment: what have you tried? looking e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885760/scraping-and-web-crawling-framework-php should give you some starting info

Comment: I've looked into CURL, but I've spent a few hours with it, and it seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: see, that's the info that you should put into the question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php script:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://yourUrl.com');
echo $html;
```

If you need more advanced functionality, like simulating Headers/Cookies, look into - `cURL`.